# Show XML text from button click instead of downloading it - PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, post, phantomjs

I have the problem below:

I did a c# program to get information from a website using phantomjs, the information that I need is from a button that when clicks, downloads a xml file directly. How can I cheat the button to instead of download the file directly just show all the xml text in phantom?

This is what I have in the Request Header:

```
Chave   Valor
Solicitar   POST /importacaoweb-7/ConsultarDiXml.do HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, 
image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, 
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer https://www1c.siscomex.receita.fazenda.gov.br/importacaoweb-
7/ConsultarDI.do
Accept-Language pt-BR
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 
3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    www1c.siscomex.receita.fazenda.gov.br
Content-Length  21
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie 
JSESSIONID= ......
LtpaToken2= ......
```

If I send the href with the Request Body (that is the code that I have here), nothing happens.
Does anyone already tried this and can help me?

If I was not clear please let me know and contact me that I will try to explain better to get help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a certificate.  See webpage : https://www1.siscomex.receita.fazenda.gov.br/siscomexImpweb-7/login_cert.jsp

Comment: Yes, I have the certificate, I get the xml file but I want to get instead the text. @jdweng

Comment: If the server automatically save xml as file there is nothing you can do.  If the data is returned in a Response then the text is the response.OuterXml().

Comment: In the browser console the response is bringing the xml text, but when I try to navigate to the page in my code, it comes empty and then there is nothing to get in outerXML, how can I get the information from response? @jdweng

Comment: It you have text string then use either XmlDocument Parse(string) or XDocument.Parrse(string).